# Mitigating memory leaks by forking

Tags: c, linux, memory, resources, posix

This is a really ugly question.

I have a C++ program which does the following in a loop:

- Waits for a JMS message
- Calculates some data
- Sends a JMS message in response

My program (let's call it "Bob") has a rather severe memory leak. The memory leak is located in a shared library that someone else wrote, which I must use, but the source code to which I do not have access.

This memory leak causes Bob to crash during the "calculates some data" phase of the loop. This is a problem, because another program is awaiting Bob's response, and will be very upset if it does not receive one.

Due to various restrictions (yes, this is an X/Y problem, I told you it was ugly), I have determined that my only viable strategy is to modify Bob so that it does the following in its loop:

- Waits for a JMS message
- Calculates some data
- Sends a JMS message in response
- Checks to see whether it's in danger of using "too much" memory
- If so, forks and execs another copy of itself, and gracefully exits

My question is as follows:

What is the best (reliable but not too inefficient) way to detect whether we're using "too much" memory? My current thought is to compare `getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS) rlim_cur` to `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF) ru_maxrss`; is that correct? If not, what's a better way? Bob runs in a Linux VM on various host machines, all with different amounts of memory.

Comment: Assuming the memory leak occurs in the "Calculates some data" phase, I'm wondering if it would make more sense to just refactor that portion into a separate program and fork out to execute that in a separate memory space.  That way you can at least isolate the offending code and make it easier to replace it in the future, rather than just masking the problem by having the program restart itself when it runs low on memory.  That's just a thought - without seeing the code, I can't say whether or not it's a viable option for you.

Comment: as a workaround; why not exit each time a computation is done and re-launch the program each time?

Comment: Jean, at the extreme end that is viable. I'm wondering if it's possible to cut down on the overhead by only restarting when strictly necessary.

Comment: Or relaunch after servicing some other fixed, conservatively chosen number of requests.

Comment: Jeff: Not only is that a brilliant idea, it completely gets rid of the need to measure memory usage! The parent can handle messages and monitor the state of its child, passing information through low-level IPC and restarting the child on SIGCHILD. Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: John, I did consider that, but unfortunately the rate of memory leak depends on the contents of the messages, too, not just the number of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the memory leak occurs in the "Calculates some data" phase, I think it might make more sense to just refactor that portion into a separate program and fork out to execute that in its own process. That way you can at least isolate the offending code and make it easier to replace it in the future, rather than just masking the problem by having the program restart itself when it runs low on memory.

The "Calculates some data" part can either be a long-running process that waits for requests from the main program and restarts itself when necessary, or (even simpler) it could be a one-and-done program that just takes its data in `*argv` and sends its results to `stdout`.  Then your main loop can just fork out and exec it every time through, and read the results when they come back.  I would go with the simpler option if possible, but that will of course depend on what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the program itself restart or fork the "Calculates some data" section to a separate process, in any case you'll need to check for the memory consumption. Since you're on Linux, an easy way to check this is to get the pid number of the process of interest, and read the contents of the file `/proc/$PID/statm`. The second number is the size of the resident set.

Reading these proc files are the way tools like top and htop get the data about processes. Reading a ~30-byte in-memory file periodically to check the memory leak doesn't sound too inefficient.

If the leak is regular and you want to make it a bit more sophisticated, you could even keep track of the rate of growth and adjust your rate of checks accordingly.